# How can I send user Infos from the login endpoint to the frontend when utilizing Google Login?

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api, google-api

I am in the process of developing a website with a separated front-end and back-end architecture.
Here is the code snippet for my endpoint, which is implemented using an ASP.NET Core Web API project:

```
[HttpPost("GoogleLogin")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult ValidGoogleLogin()
{
    string? formCredential = Request.Form["credential"]; //Return credential
    string? formToken = Request.Form["g_csrf_token"]; // Return token
    string? cookiesToken = Request.Cookies["g_csrf_token"]; // Cookie token
    // Verify Google Token
    GoogleJsonWebSignature.Payload? payload = VerifyGoogleToken(formCredential, formToken, cookiesToken).Result;
    if (payload == null)
    {
        // Verification failed
        return BadRequest("驗證 Google 授權失敗");
    }
    else
    {
        // Verification successful, construct the response object
        var result = new
        {
            Msg = "Google authorization verification successful",
            Email = payload.Email,
            Name = payload.Name,
            Picture = payload.Picture
        };
        return Ok(result);
        //return Redirect("http://localhost:5501/index.html");
    }
}

private async Task<GoogleJsonWebSignature.Payload?> VerifyGoogleToken(string? formCredential, string? formToken, string? cookiesToken)
{
    // Check for null values
    if (formCredential == null || formToken == null && cookiesToken == null)
    {
    return null;
    }

    GoogleJsonWebSignature.Payload? payload;
    try
    {
        // Verify token
        if (formToken != cookiesToken)
        {
            return null;
        }

        // Verify credential
        //IConfiguration Config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appSettings.json").Build();
        string GoogleApiClientId = _config["GoogleAuthentication:ClientId"];
        var settings = new GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidationSettings()
        {
            Audience = new List<string>() { GoogleApiClientId }
        };
        payload = await GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidateAsync(formCredential, settings);
        if (!payload.Issuer.Equals("accounts.google.com") && !payload.Issuer.Equals("https://accounts.google.com"))
        {
            return null;
        }
        if (payload.ExpirationTimeSeconds == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
            DateTime expiration = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds((long)payload.ExpirationTimeSeconds).DateTime;
            if (now > expiration)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
    return payload;
}
```

In my front-end HTML:

```
<div id="g_id_onload"
    data-client_id="MyClientId"
    data-context="signin" data-ux_mode="popup"
    data-login_uri="https://localhost:520/api/Members/GoogleLogin"
    data-auto_prompt="false">
</div>

<div class="g_id_signin" 
    data-type="standard" 
    data-shape="rectangular" 
    data-theme="outline"
    data-text="signin" 
    data-size="large" 
    data-logo_alignment="left">
</div>
```

I am aiming to retrieve the response on the front-end, possibly using a statement like

```
let res = axios.post(url,data)
let myDatas = response.data;
...
```

I have consulted the following documents:

- Display Google Sign-In button:
  **https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/display-button#html**
- HTML Reference:
  **https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/html-reference#attribute-types**
- JS Reference:
  **https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#login_uri**
- Handle Credential Responses:
  **https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/handle-credential-responses-js-functions**

Despite referring to these resources, I am still facing difficulties in finding a solution.
Could you guide me on what steps I should take next?